# Download different file to that requested php

Tags: php, http-headers, joomla3.0

In Joomla auto updater the file is requested from one domain

```
http://download.abc.com/?ext=addmenu&src=core&pro=1&file=update.zip
```

which then downloads a different file

```
/mnt/storage/vhosts/newdomain.com/httpdocs/tmp/addmenu-v1.1.4.zip
```

I've been trying to mimic this effect by calling a file release.php which is

```
header("Location: /addmenu/updates/com_addmenu.zip");
```

but it just downloads release.php and not com_addmenu.zip

I've also tried it with

```
header('HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect');
```

before the header(Location

But I can't get it to work this way.  I'm guessing that I'm not able to substitute one file for another but I'm hoping someone can help.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you have a zip file on your server which shall be downloaded under a different name by the visitor's browser when s/he opens up your webpage.php.

```
<?php
$file_url = '/addmenu/updates/release.zip';
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=com_addmenu.zip'); 
readfile($file_url);
```

Comment: thanks.  It's joomla that is making the download request to the other site and I want the reply to be a different file.  I tried you code and it doesn't work